# JSON usage while autofill the form when user changes the category

Tags: php, mysql, json, autofill

i'm trying to fill the form with database information when user changes the category(select tag changes). here is my code.

```
<form onsubmit='return false'>
select<select id="select">
       <option value='5'>5</option>
       <option value='6'>6</option>
       <option value='7'>7</option>
       <option value='8'>8</option>
       <option value='9'>9</option>
       <option value='10'>10</option>
       </select>
       fname<input type="text" id='fname' name="fname" /><br />
       lname<input type="text" id='lname' name="lname" /><br />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select").change(function(){
        selectid = $(this).val();
          // using post method to get firstname   
                     $.post("retreive.php", {selectid:selectid}, function(result){
                            $("#fname").val();
                            //again using post method here get lastname
                           $.post("one.php", {selectid:selectid}, function(result){
                             $("#lname").val();

                           });
                      });   
     });    
});
```

retreive.php

```
<?php
//for firstname
if( isset($_POST['selectid']) ){
     //using this selectid i'm getting firstname
     echo $firstname;
     exit();
}

//again for last name
if( isset($_POST['selectid']) ){
     //using this selectid i'm getting firstname
     echo $lastname;
     exit();
}
?>
```

Finally this procedure auto filling the form fields i.e; firstname and lastname. I know this is foolish and time taken procedure. I've heard that this work done easily and no need to make our php bare all that burden with using the concept of JSON. I have tried to understand but couldn't. I hope you guys can understand the problem i'm facing, hoping for a solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are made ajax request, but **do nothing** with result data.
Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select").change(function(){
       var selectid = $(this).val();
          // using post method to get firstname   
                     $.post("retreive.php", {selectid:selectid}, function(result){
                            $("#fname").val(result);
                            //again using post method here get lastname
                           $.post("one.php", {selectid:selectid}, function(result){
                             $("#lname").val(result);

                           });
                      });   
     });    
});
```

You don't need two ajax requests - you can make one request, and get json data.
Read about [jquery ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and json format

```
$(function(){
 $('#select').change(function(){
 var selectid = $(this).val();
 $.ajax({
  url: 'retreive.php',
  data: {selectid: selectid},
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data)
  {
    $("#fname").val(result.fname);
    $("#lname").val(result.lname);
  }
});
});
});
```

And php

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['selectid'])) {
  echo json_encode(array('fname' => $fname, 'lname' => $lname));
  exit;
 }
```

And if something goes wrong, when you made ajax request, open console, and find errors. If you have no errors, go for the network and see what server returns you.

Comment: Thank you @Andery Vorobyev, using that selectid value i can retrieve fname, lname and i'll keep in an array as u showed in php file. But what if i have retrieved a record that contains 20 to 30 fields? should i follow the same process i.e; array('fname'=>$fname, 'lname'=>$lname, 'address'=>$adress, 'mob'=>$mob,....... upto 20/30...'city'=>$city, ).

Comment: in php echo json_encode(array(array('fname' => $fname, 'lname' => $lname), array('fname' => $fname, 'lname' => $lname))); In javascript you get array of objects, and you can show it how you needs

Comment: Just success callback parameter 'data' needs to be changed into 'result'. Realizing now how important the JSON concept is....Thank you very much @Andrey Vorobyev you solved the problem.

Comment: i'm trying to get data from mysql 'users' table using that 'selectid', using mysql_fetch_array() i'm getting fname, lname after that i'm echoing as below. but nothing happened. Is there any other way to deal with sql data or am i doing any mistake while i'm echoing ?

echo json_encode(array('fname'=>$fname, 'lname'=>$lname));

Comment: what encoding you are using in mysql database and connection? JSON data must be in UTF-8
And close question please =)

Comment: Everything is working fine now! it was typo error in my code that's all. Thanks for all guys! and how to close the question? Is there any Procedure to close or you telling to stop commenting :-)? Let me know if any.

Comment: I'm very happy for you =) To close the question you need to select the best answer.